# How to execute function from shared object (.so)

Tags: c, go, shared-libraries

I have a .so file which was generated from C code, let assume that it contains function named `example_function`. I want to execute function from shared object in Go.

In python I can call it like this:

```
import ctypes
c_API = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./libAPI.so")
c_API.example_function(arguments)
```

How can I achieve analogous functionality in Go?

Comment: How does python related to your question?

Comment: You need [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [some `dlopen` package](https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/pkg/dlopen).

Be sure to read before implementation details explained in [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html).

See also Go code in [monimelt](https://github.com/bstarynk/monimelt), etc...